# Nyasa etc for Lalita Sahasranama

Tags: rituals, stotra, lalita

Hari Om,

I'm looking for a source of explanation of the procedure of using the Nyasas of Lalita Sahasranama. See below.

Would be much appreciated. -Hari

अस्य श्रीललितासहस्रनामस्तोत्रमहामन्त्रस्य वशिन्यादयो वाग्देवता ऋषयः ।
अनुष्टुप् छन्दः । श्रीललिता परमेश्वरी देवता ।
श्रीमद्बाग्भवकूटेति बीजम् । मध्यकूटेति शक्तिः ।
शक्तिकूटेति कीलकम् । ध्यानम् ।
मम श्रीललितामहात्रिपुरसुन्दरीप्रसादसिद्धिद्वारा
चिन्तितफलावाप्त्यर्थे जपे विनियोगः ।
॥ करन्यासः ॥

ऐं अङ्गुष्ठाभ्यां नमः । क्लीं तर्जनीभ्यां नमः ।
सौः मध्यमाभ्यां नमः । सौः अनामिकाभ्यां नमः ।
क्लीं कनिष्ठिकाभ्यां नमः । ऐं करतलकरपृष्ठाभ्यां नमः ।
॥ अङ्गन्यासः ॥

ऐं हृदयाय नमः । क्लीं शिरसे स्वाहा । सौः शिखायै वषट् ।
सौः कवचाय हुं । क्लीं नेत्रत्रयाय वौषट् । ऐं अस्त्राय फट् ।
भूर्भवस्सुवरोमिति दिग्बन्धः ।

लमित्यादिपञ्चपूजा
`लं'' पृथिवीतत्त्वात्मिकायै श्रीललितादेव्यै गन्धं परिकल्पयामि ।`
हं'' आकाशतत्त्वात्मिकायै श्रीललितादेव्यै पुष्पं परिकल्पयामि ।
`यं'' वायुतत्त्वात्मिकायै श्रीललितादेव्यै धूपं परिकल्पयामि ।`
रं'' वह्नितत्त्वात्मिकायै श्रीललितादेव्यै दीपं परिकल्पयामि ।
`वं'' अमृततत्त्वामिकायै श्रीललितादेव्यै अमृतं महानैवेद्यं परिकल्पयामि ।`
सं'' सर्वतत्त्वात्मिकायै श्रीललितादेव्यै सर्वोपचारपूजां परिकल्पयामि ।

Comment: Also the Mudras/procedures for Nyasa remain the same irrespective of the Mantra/Stotra you are doing it for. Only the Nyasa Mantras change accordingly.

Comment: What is ur response to my answer? Have u understood how the Nyasas are to be done from my answer? Chk the site I have linked in my answer. There they hv described how to do the Nyasas for Shodashi Mantra Japa of Goddess Lalita.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry, I couldn't' respond earlier. If one is not initiated in the Bala or Panchadasi mantra then which prefixes to choose before the kara and Anga nyasa?

Comment: For this Stotram the Mantras (prefixes in ur words) are fixed; they can not be changed. You hv to chant whatever is given in it. Yes without initiation it is not recommended to do the Nyasas.

Comment: But the Nyasas can also be done with Panchadasi mantra correct?

Comment: Yes Nyasas are also done during Panchadashi Mantra japa. The procedures will be the same. Only here we are saying say " Aim hridaya namah" there we will have to say "(something else and not Aim) hridaya namaha" .. this is the only difference .. similarly for the rest. Also the Nyasa procedures remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Rick Ross. Your time and effort is appriciated.

Comment: No problem bro but it's sad to see that you have deleted ur account. You could have stayed IMO. :)

Comment: What explanation? Make your question clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First see how the Rishyadi Nyasas are done. These Nyasas are done with the right hand using the Tattva Mudra/Nyasa Mudra which is formed by joining the thumb and the ring finger at the tips.

- When you say " ... vagdevata rshiayah" touch the top of your head with the right hand in Tattva Mudra.
- While saying "Anushtupa Chandah" touch similarly the upper lips (or upper porting of the upper lip).
- While specifying the Devata (Sri Lalita Parameswari Devata) touch the heart (middle of the chest).
- While saying "Srimad vagbhavakuteti bijam" touch similarly the right shoulder.
- While saying " Madhya kuteti shakti" touch the left shoulder with the same Mudra.
- And, while saying "Shaktikuteti Kilakam" similarly touch the navel.

Here ends, Rishyadi Nyasas.

Next comes the Kara Nyasas:

While saying "Aim angushtabhyam namaha" run all four fingers from the base till the tip of the thumb. While saying " Kilm tarjanibhayam namaha" run the thumb from the base till the tip of the index finger. Similarly we do for the remaining fingers ( Anamika=ring finger, Madhyama=middle finger and Kanishtika=Little finger).

These Nyasas are done on both the hands simultaneously.

And, while saying "Aim karatala kara prishtabhyam namaha" open both the palms; run the opened palms of the right hand on the front and back sides of the left palm and repeat the same for the other palm) (Reference-[Astrojyoti.com](http://www.astrojyoti.com/shodasimantra.htm))

And, then comes Anga Nyasas:

While saying "Aim hridaya namaha" touch the region of heart with the right hand's index, middle and ring fingers (leaving the thumb and little fingers out).

While saying "Klim shirase swaha" touch the top of the head with the right hand's middle and ring fingers.

While saying "Sauh shikhayai vaushat" touch the back side of the head with the right hand thumb only.

While saying "Sauh kavachaya hum" keep the right hand open palm on the left shoulder and the left hand open palm on the right shoulder with the hands crossing each other or else do like this - cross both the hands and run the fully opened palms from shoulders to finger tips.

While saying "Klim netratraya oushat" open the three fingers - index, middke and ring - of the right hand and place the index on the right eye, middle on the third eye (middle of the eyebrow) and the ring on the left.

While saying "Aim astraya phat" do this - open up the left palm and strike it three times with index and middle fingers of the right hand.

While saying "Bhurbhuvasuvariti digvandaha" we draw a protective circle around us by doing like this - by using right hand thumb and middle fingers make rattle clockwise around the head. (there should be eight rattles made signifying the eight directions).

**Note of caution:**

If you do not have any experiences with how to do Nyasas then it is unlikely that you can follow the steps given and do it correctly. Also, not everyone can do these Nyasas. Only after initiations the Guru will teach these things to the disciples.